# Protractor - looping through different locators to populate array

Tags: javascript, arrays, protractor

I'm using protractor and I want to loop through a series of locators(all with different names) to get the text being displayed and then compare that to an array of expected values.

I've come accross examples like below:

```
var expected = ['expect1', 'expect2', 'expect3'];
var els = element.all(by.css('selector'));
for (var i = 0; i < expected.length; ++i) {
    expect(els.get(i).getText()).toEqual(expected[i]);
}
```

where you can do a comparison against a locators children, but not from different locators.

How would you adapt something like the one above to loop through a list of locators(like below) and then compare that to a series of values in another array.

```
const locators = {
    emp: by.id('employmentError'),
    occ: by.id('occupationError'),
    stat: by.id('statError'),
    show: by.id('showError')
};
```

The comparison part seems easier, it is populating the initial array full of text from various locators I can't get my head around.

Comment: Would each of the locators have a different array to compare to? So would `emp` need to compare with `empExpected` and `occ` need to compare with `occExpected` for example

Comment: nope, it would be all the locators , emp, occ etc against an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Protractor methods return promises. So it's safer to use promises every time because they are asyn operations.
Try the following code:

```
const locators = {
    emp: element(by.id('employmentError')),
    occ: element(by.id('occupationError')),
    stat: element(by.id('statError')),
    show: element(by.id('showError'))
}; 
var promises = [], texts = [];
var els = element.all(by.css('selector'));
els.forEach(els, function(el) {
  els.getText().then(function(text) {
    texts.push(text);
  });
});
for (var i in locators) {
  promises.push(locators[i].getText());
}
expect(protractor.promise.all(promises)).to.become(texts);
```

Comment: I use cucumber with protractor...so in your reply, I would want to do the latter part, go through the locators and put all the text into an array. then return that array to my step definitions where I do my comparison. How would I return the locators text in an array in a function?

Comment: I use cucumber as well with protractor. You can define the table of texts inside your .feature file, get the table rows inside your step definition, and then compare it directly to the array of promises. 
Actually you can directly avoid the texts part and use the rows defined in the tables within the feature files.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to collect elements that correspond to different types of errors. What if you would get all of them with a *unified locator*, like:

```
var errors = $$("[id$=Error]");
expect(errors.getText()).toEqual([
    "Employment Error happened",
    "Some other error" 
]);
```

Here `errors` would locate the elements with `id` attributes ending with "Error".

Comment: how would you tweak this to create a function that put all these errors into an array and returned that array?

Comment: @Curious_Bop well, the thing is, `errors.getText()` is a promise that would resolve into a array of error texts..